# Python Error(Beginner)

Tags: python, wxpython

I been learning python the last day or so using online tutorials I found, everything has been coming along well till I got an error that I can not seem to fix.

The site I been using today is http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started

I have got all the way to sizers with little trouble. When I try to run a program from the tutorial I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Python27/test.pyw", line 4, in 
>   class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
>   File "C:/Python27/test.pyw", line 8, in MainWindow
>   wx.Frame.**init**(self,parent,title=title,size=(200,-1))
>   NameError: name 'self' is not defined

```
import wx
import os

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        self.dirname=''

    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(200,-1))
    self.control=wx.TextCtrl(self,style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    self.CreateStatusBar()

    filemenu=wx.Menu()
    menuOpen=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,'&Open','Open a file to edit')
    menuAbout=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,"&About","Information about this program")
    menuExit=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit","Terminate the program")

    menuBar=wx.MenuBar()
    menuBar.Append(filemenu,'&File')
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnOpen,menuOpen)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnExit,menuExit)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU.self.OnAbout,menuAbout)

    self.sizer2=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.buttons=[]
    for i in range(0,6):
        self.buttons.append(wx.Button(self,-1,'button &'+str(i)))
        self.sizer2.Add(self.buttons[i],1,wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizers(self.sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Show()

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg=wx.MessageDialog(self,'A sample editor \n in wxPython', 'About sample editor', wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnOpen(self,e):
        dlg=wx.FileDialog(self,"choose a file", self.dirname,"","*.*",wx.OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
            f=open(os.path.join(self.dirname,self.filename),'r')
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

    app=wx.App(False)
    frame=MainWindow(None,'Sample editor')
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have been working at this for about a hour. Re-typed and checked over several times.  Any help in the form of advice or other tutorials would be greatly appreciated. Also, is there any list of common errors anywhere?

Comment: If you're learning a new language, just don't start with gui. Start with simple console apps.

Comment: It looks to me as if you need to remove the indentation from your last three lines:  `app=wx.App(False)`,  `frame=MainWindow(None,'Sample editor')`, and  
`app.MainLoop()`  
However, I can't confirm, as I don't have wx installed.

Answer (score 3):

Everything from `wx.Frame.__init__(...)` up to but not including the next `def` [must be indented one additional level](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming).

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error: everything from the 8th line down should be indented to match the previous lines.